# Google Sheets - How to concatenate cells that meet a condition

Tags: concatenation, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I need to concatenate data from multiple rows/columns but skip columns where the value for the column is "None". I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:F5<>"None",B4:F4&" - "&B5:F5, "")))`

Explanation:

Use `TEXTJOIN` to join all the "A - 4 to 3" together with commas while skipping empty strings.

Use `ARRAYFORMULA` and `IF` so that you concat row4 with row5 if value in row5 is not equal to "None", otherwise return empty string.